# Tailwind Css Custom Animation on Hover

Tags: animation, hover, tailwind-css

I created an eye icon animation with tailwind however I could not make it on hover :( Could you please guide me on how can animate on hover? :)

[Tailwind Eye-Icon-Animation](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Su9KLbCCuI)

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend `animation` in your config to support `hover` and `group-hover` variants

```html
<div class="h-36 w-36 mx-auto flex justify-center items-center group hover:animate-roll">
  <div class="h-full w-full bg-black transform rotate-45 border-radius-eye flex justify-center items-center"> </div>
  <div class="h-12 w-12  bg-white rounded-full z-10 absolute group-hover:animate-movement" ></div>
</div>
```

#### tailwind.config.js

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
      roll: { 
          '0%, 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 60%, 70%, 80%, 90%, 100%': { transform: 'scale(1)'},
          '50%': { transform: 'scaleY(0)' }
        },

        movement: {
          '0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%': { transform: 'translateX(0rem)' },
          '10%': { transform: 'translateX(2rem)' },
          '30%': { transform: 'translateX(-2rem)' },
          '50%': { transform: 'translateY(1rem)' },
          '70%': { transform: 'translateY(-1rem)' },
        }

      },
      animation: {
        roll: 'roll 3s infinite ',
        movement: 'movement 5s infinite'
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      animation: ['hover', 'group-hover'] 
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

> Note: As your parent element has `flex` class, it has full width meaning that on hover of whole line (not only eye) hover effect has taken place. To prevent it, I've relocated `h-36` and `w-36` from 'eye' to a wrapper and add `mx-auto` to center it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I appreciated that's working just the thing is only the blink animation is working now however the second animation "movement of the eye-ball" is not working :( 

https://play.tailwindcss.com/m5KKmDYgXa

Comment: you has `group:animate-roll` in example but it should be `group-hover:animate-movement`

Comment: yeah realized that but not working when I changed that :( 
https://play.tailwindcss.com/bztmKDf8pt

Comment: Not `group:animate-movement` but `group-hover:animate-movement` :) https://play.tailwindcss.com/fqQk4wmqtx

Comment: Perfect bro! Thanks a lot for your support!! Phew! that's was my first animation on Tailwind :)